# Assign previous property values to next property in c#

Tags: c#

Here is my sample code

I have a class named as `Employee` with some properties

I want to assign some values to my class properties, like this way

```
Employee obj = new Employee()
{
 userName="aaa@aa.com",

 email=userName
}
```

It threw an error:

> The user name does not exist in this context

I know it is possible to do this way:

```
Employee obj = new Employee()    
 obj.userName="aaa@aa.com",  
 obj.email=userName
```

But I don't want it. How can I assign prev property to my next property?

### Edit

Actually I have using this class inside of LINQ query select function , So i can't assign the object globally.

This is my full original code

```
*PersonalRequestModel model = new PersonalRequestModel();
            model = (from personal in this.travelContext.RecruitmentJobs
                     join jobdesc in this.travelContext.JobDescriptions on personal.id equals jobdesc.recruitmentJobId into job
                     from jobd in job.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where personal.id == modelId
                     // where personal.id == modelId
                     select new
                     {
                         gjobdescription = jobd,
                         gpersonal = personal
                     }).GroupBy(x => x.gpersonal.id)
                     .Select(personalother => new PersonalRequestModel
                     {
                         jobdescrip = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gjobdescription,
                         recuritmentjob = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal,
                         //recuritmentjob = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal,
                         personalviewdetail = new PersonalRequestDisplayModel
                         {
                             Gender = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gjobdescription.recruitmentJobId == personalother.Key).gjobdescription.gender,
                             TypeOfVacancy = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.typeOfVacancy,
                             newOrReplacement = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.newOrReplacement,
                             Designation = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.designation,
                             DateOfRequest = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.dateOfRequest,
                             HeadCount = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.headcount,
                             division = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.division,
                             HiringDepartment = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.hiringDepartment,
                             budgetorNonbudget = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.budgetorNonbudget,
                             Qualificationdesc = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.educationalQualification,
                             expectedDateOfJoin = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.expectedDateOfJoin,
                             ReasonForRequest = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.reason,
                             noofcandiate = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.noofCandidate,
                             workexp = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.workExperience,
                             eduqual = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.educationalQualification,
                             //isReplacementEmpNo = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.isReplacementEmpNo,
                             // isReplacementName = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.isReplacementEmpNo,
                             isTemporaryPeriod = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.isTemporaryPeriod,
                             hrApprovalStatus = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.hrApprovalStatus,
                             hrApprovalDate = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.hrApprovalDate,
                             hrApprovalRemarks = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.hrApprovalRemarks,
                             level2ApprovalStatus = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.level2ApprovalStatus,
                             level2ApprovalDate = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.level2ApprovalDate,
                             level2ApprovalRemarks = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.level2ApprovalRemarks,
                             level3ApprovalStatus = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.level3ApprovalStatus,
                             level3ApprovalDate = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.level3ApprovalDate,
                             level3ApprovalRemarks = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.level3ApprovalRemarks,
                             h1ApprovalStatus = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.h1ApprovalStatus,
                             h1ApprovalDate = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.h1ApprovalDate,
                             h1ApprovalRemarks = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.h1ApprovalRemarks,
                             h2ApprovalStatus = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.h2ApprovalStatus,
                             h2ApprovalDate = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.h2ApprovalDate,
                             h2ApprovalRemarks = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.h2ApprovalRemarks,
                             h3ApprovalStatus = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.h3ApprovalStatus,
                             h3ApprovalDate = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.h3ApprovalDate,
                             h3ApprovalRemarks = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.h3ApprovalRemarks,
                             positionName = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.positionName,
                             positionNumber = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.positionNumber,
                             orgchart = personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.orgChartUrl,
                             l2approvaluserid = this.travelContext.EmployeeReportingLevels.Where(e => e.userId == personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.createdBy).FirstOrDefault().level2,
                             l3approvaluserid = this.travelContext.EmployeeReportingLevels.Where(e => e.userId == personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.createdBy).FirstOrDefault().level3,
                             h1approvaluserid = this.travelContext.EmployeeReportingLevels.Where(e => e.userId == personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.createdBy).FirstOrDefault().h1,
                             h2approvaluserid = this.travelContext.EmployeeReportingLevels.Where(e => e.userId == personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.createdBy).FirstOrDefault().h2,
                             h3approvaluserid = this.travelContext.EmployeeReportingLevels.Where(e => e.userId == personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.createdBy).FirstOrDefault().h3,
                             ID = modelId,
                             l2Name = this.travelContext.Employees.Where(emp => emp.userId == l2approvaluserid).FirstOrDefault().firstName,
                         },
                         //    jobdescrip = personalother.Select(x => x.gjobdescription).Distinct().ToList()
                     }).FirstOrDefault();*
```

Error has been throw in `l2Name`  property

Comment: Your `obj.userName` and `userName` are different things? Is `userName` a local variable?

Comment: Tidy up that code, and then point out which bit is actually relevant to your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object initializer blocks cannot reference the object being created, because it doesn't exist yet. This is a constraint in the compiler and you cannot get around it.

I'd recommend you to inject the value via the constructor and set it internally. This way you protect your invariants more and can make the class immutable.

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee(string email)
    {
        UserName = email;
        Email = email;
    }

    public string UserName { get; }
    public string Email { get; }
}
```

EDIT: If it's ALWAYS the case that the user name is equal to the email address I'd probably even just do the following:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee(string email)
    {
        Email = email;
    }

    public string UserName => Email;
    public string Email { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this way

```
var str = "aaa@aa.com"
Employee obj = new Employee()
{
 userName=str,

 email=str
}
```

In your case, the code goes like

```
 var _l2approvaluserid = this.travelContext.EmployeeReportingLevels.Where(e => e.userId == personalother.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gpersonal.id == personalother.Key).gpersonal.createdBy).FirstOrDefault().level2;
 personalviewdetail = new PersonalRequestDisplayModel
   {
     ....
     l2approvaluserid = _l2approvaluserid;
     ....
     l2Name = this.travelContext.Employees.Where(emp => emp.userId == _l2approvaluserid).FirstOrDefault().firstName,

  }
```

But if i have similar code, i would not use object initializer. It makes debugging a bit more difficult if there is any issue.

Comment: ha ha,  I know some one put this type of answers. Please wait i will edit my question \

Comment: @RameshRajendran: Yeah, because it's the best solution

Comment: As Kai has mentioned, it is a compiler restriction, and you cannot get away as of c# 6. There may be a special syntax to allow this in future.